# Can xsd.exe's generated classes identify required attributes

Tags: xsd.exe

Is it possible to have xsd.exe add "IsNullable=false" to XmlAttributes for fields/properties that are defined in the schema as being required?

Xjc adds it to the Java annotation, but I haven't found a way to get Xsd.exe to do something similar.

I'm trying to use reflection to do a merge of our configuration files that isn't configuration file type dependent. I want to use the required attributes of an element to determine if that element exists in both files or just one.